# FCM OAuth2.0 access token creation throwing "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]" error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, jwt, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im trying to use JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) to mint access tokens for Firebase Cloud Messaging, but I am having difficulty applying the given token to the `FCM HTTP v1 API` request headers. The function worked outside of my cloud function when I was using Postman to test and I was able to create a token and successfully send a push notification using this function in `index.js`:

```js
async function getAccessToken(keyFile = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

    const keys = require(keyFile)
    const client = new JWT({
      email: keys.client_email,
      key: keys.private_key,
      scopes: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform',
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging'
      ]
    });

    client.authorize((err, tokens) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err)
        return
      }
      resolve(tokens.access_token.replace(/\.+$/, ''))
    })
  })
}
```

Within `my-cloud-function.js` file, I add this same function into my cloud function, remove it from `index.js`(it was there for testing purposes) and try to send the FCM like so:

```js
await fetch(`https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${my-project}/messages:send`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
         'Authorization': getAccessToken()
    },
    body: {
        "message": {
          "topic": `${my-topic}`,
          "notification": {
            "title": "Test",
            "body": "Testing."
          },
        }
    },
})
    .then((response) => {
        response.json().then(res => {
            functions.logger.log('res', res)
            functions.logger.log('token::::', getAccessToken())
        })
        .catch(e => {
            functions.logger.log('an error here', e)
        })
    })
    .catch(error => {
        functions.logger.log('error:', error)
    })
```

Again, this post request worked in Postman. The error I get in the cloud functions log is:

```js
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "id" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:124:11)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:3)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at /workspace/my-cloud-function.js:11:22
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at getAccessToken (/workspace/my-cloud-function.js:10:12)
    at /workspace/my-cloud-function.js:95:59
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

The error points to lines 10, 11, and 95. Line 11 is `const keys = require(keyFile)` and Line 95 is `functions.logger.log('token::::', getAccessToken())`. I read online that the `require` statement takes a string, which I thought `keyFile` is. It worked in Postman, but I am stuck now. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to use JWTs, I finally figured out how to authenticate cloud messages using the Firebase Admin SDK. In my `index.js` file, I have:

```js
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
});
```

In order for this to work, I had to find my function inside the Google Cloud Platform website, edit the function, click on `Runtime, build, connections and security settings` , -> `Runtime`, -> `Runtime service account` and choose the Admin SDK service account deploy from there.